# Rewrite default post type

Tags: url-rewriting, site-url

I would like to rewrite the default post type URL to `/blog/2016/11/my-post-name/` without affect the other post type url. I tried:

```
add_action('admin_menu','remove_default_post_type');
function remove_default_post_type() {
    remove_menu_page('edit.php');
}

add_action( 'init', 'set_default_post_type', 1 );

function set_default_post_type() {
register_post_type( 
    'post',
        array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name_admin_bar' => _x( 'Post', 'add new on admin bar' ),
        ),
        'public' => true,
        '_builtin' => false,
        '_edit_link' => 'post.php?post=%d',
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'map_meta_cap' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'blog/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/',
            'with_front'=> false,
        ),
        'query_var' => false,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'comments', 'revisions', 'post-formats' ),
    ) 
 );
}
```

But with no success. The url stay as `/blog/my-post`. Is there one way to have permalinks of default post type like `/blog/2016/11/my-post-name/` (where 2016 is the year of post and 11 is the month of post) Without affect others post types urls?

Comment: you can't re-register a built-in post type, post permalink is controlled by Settings > Permalinks page, you can get the format you want there.

Comment: @Milo I tried this config in admin with blog/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/ in admin panel but this affect other custom post type that already exists in the project including yoast breadcrumb trail

Comment: custom post types should be registered with `with_front` set to `false` so the post permalink structure is not prepended.

Comment: @Milo as an answer please :)

Comment: @Milo you're right.. Please make an answer ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the field in the admin `Settings > Permalinks` page to set your permalink structure to `/blog/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/`.

To prevent custom post types from inheriting the post permalink structure, set `with_front` to `false` in your `register_post_type` arguments for all custom post types.

Version 4.4 also added the [`register_post_type_args`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/register_post_type_args/) filter to allow modification of post type arguments for types registered by code you don't have access to change.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Custom Permalink` plugin https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/

But it can't use permalink "templates". You will need to enter your custom permalink for each post on editing page.